# How to delete zip file after sent response in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I just want to delete zip folder after sent response  so I am looking for any alternative solution

Here is my code / it is get request

```
exports.Download = async (req, res) => {
       try {
        var zp = new admz();
        zp.addLocalFolder(`./download/${folder}`);
        const file_after_download = 'downloaded.zip';
        const data = zp.toBuffer();
        res.set('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
        res.set('Content-Disposition', `attachment; filename=${file_after_download}`);
        res.set('Content-Length', data.length);
        return res.send(data);
        
        // HERE I want execute this code 
        let dir = `./download/${folder}`;
        if (fse.existsSync(dir)) {
            fse.rmdirSync(dir, { recursive: true })
        }
         
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return res.render('pages/404');
    }
}
```

**Update**

1. If send code without `return` ( res.send(data);)
   Im getting this error //Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client //
2. If I put `return res.send(data);` at the end of block , then downloaded zip file will be empty - because its deleted already

Comment: Why do you `return` prematurely if you have code you *need* to run after where you have that statement currently…? Can you explain in your own words what you *believe* the `return` keyword does in JavaScript? I suspect that’s where your understanding is breaking down.

Comment: What happens if you put the `return` at the end?

Comment: Remove `return` in front of `res.send(data)`.

Comment: //Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client//
I am getting this error if I put return at the end

Comment: and If I put return at end , downloading file will be empty

Comment: @ITgoldman Updated question  , please check updated content

Comment: @espew  Updated question  , please check updated content

Comment: @CherryDT Updated question  , please check updated content

Comment: The error `ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT` would only happen if two responses were sent. The only other place in your function where you send a response is `res.render('pages/404')`. So it seems your deletion fails. According to your code, you log the error into the console, so you can please check what error you get upon deletion and fix it? Also, the ZIP data is loaded into memory by your code. It doesn't matter whether you delete the source files afterwards. So, if the downloaded ZIP is "empty", something else is the issue (for example I feel it contains your 404 page HTML!).

Comment: Okay , let me experiment with your thought @CherryDT

Comment: Side note: Where does `folder` come from? If it comes from the frontend, then make sure you sanitize it, otherwise you have a path traversal vulnerability here which can be used to read and delete arbitrary folders on your server's filesystem (e.g. `folder=../../../../../../../..` to trash your whole server - although you'd run out of memory first, in this case, probably - but `folder=../../../../../../../../etc` can be a problem too, extracting data).

Comment: folder var thats is folder name

Answer (score -1):

From the [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.download) of Express, you can use `res.download()` function which has a callback parameters to be executed once download is done.

```
res.download(filePath, 'yourFileName', function(err) {
  if (err) {
    next(err)
  } else {
    console.log('Delete:', filePath);
  }
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.